# Accessing the column of the matrix

Tags: python, list, matrix

New to python. I have a matrix likes:

```
[['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
 ['B', 'Z', 'A', 'A'],
 ['0', 'B', 'A', 'A'],
 ['0', 'C', 'A', 'A']
]
```

Now how can I access the specific column ?

likes    `[A B 0 0]` `[A Z B C]`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to access a 2D matrix column wise, you have to transpose the matrix such that the columns can be accessed as rows. Python's [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) builtin can be used for matrix transpose.

```
>>> zip(*mat)[0]
('A', 'B', '0', '0')
```

On the contrary, you are using a [numpy array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) (recommended if you are performing an extended matrix manipulation), and use [numpy indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html). This would be natural

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> npmat = np.asarray(mat)
>>> npmat[:,0]
array(['A', 'B', '0', '0'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

based on your requirement, you can either transpose the entire matrix using [numpy.dstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) (if you are using numpy) or use zip to transpose before indexing column wise

```
>>> np.dstack(mat)
array([[['A', 'B', '0', '0'],
        ['A', 'Z', 'B', 'C'],
        ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
        ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A']]], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) built-in function to get the columns of an array :

```
>>> a=[['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
...  ['B', 'Z', 'A', 'A'],
...  ['0', 'B', 'A', 'A'],
...  ['0', 'C', 'A', 'A']
... ]
>>> 
>>> zip(*a)
[('A', 'B', '0', '0'), ('A', 'Z', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'A', 'A', 'A'), ('A', 'A', 'A', 'A')]
```

Or if you have a matrix in `numpy` you can use [`dstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.array([['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],['B', 'Z', 'A', 'A'],['0', 'B', 'A', 'A'],['0', 'C', 'A', 'A']])
>>> np.dstack(a)
array([[['A', 'B', '0', '0'],
        ['A', 'Z', 'B', 'C'],
        ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
        ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A']]], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Also you can [just use indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) to get a specific column :

```
>>> a[:,0]
array(['A', 'B', '0', '0'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a single column you can do (if `x` is your original array):

```
x_0 = [r[0] for r in x]
```

or if you do this a lot and can use numpy, it would look like this:

```
y = np.array(x)
y_0 = y[:,0]
```

An advantage of this approach over using `zip` and/or `dstack` is that there is minimal copying of data.